# jquery validation by date on a not required field

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have been working on this most of today and I feel that I'm stumped.

I found some code to validate a field for a mm/dd/yyyy format that is *not* required. Now this is working but for one field. I have multiple date fields that are not required but if they have something in the text field it should a date formatted as mm/dd/yyyy. I wish I could use datepicker but the client doesn't want that so it's up to validating data in text fields.

Here is the script that I'm using on the form:

```
$(function() {

  $.validator.setDefaults({
    errorClass: 'help-block',
    highlight: function(element) {
      $(element)
        .closest('.form-group')
        .addClass('has-error');
    },
    unhighlight: function(element) {
      $(element)
        .closest('.form-group')
        .removeClass('has-error');
    },
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
      if (element.prop('type') === 'radio') {
        error.insertAfter(element.parent());
      } else {
        error.insertAfter(element);
      }
    }
  });

  $.validator.addMethod(
    "goodDate",
    function(value, element) {
        // put your own logic here, this is just a (crappy) example
        return value.match(/(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)[0-9]{2}/);
    },
    "Please enter a date in the format mm/dd/yyyy."
);

  $.validator.addMethod('strongPassword', function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) 
      || value.length >= 6
      && /\d/.test(value)
      && /[a-z]/i.test(value);
  }, 'Your password must be at least 6 characters long and contain at least one number and one char\'.')






  $("#updateInprocess").validate({
    rules: {
      interview: {
        goodDate: true,
        nowhitespace: true
      },

      inp_slct_memo_recv: {
        goodDate: true,
        nowhitespace: true
      },

      inp_job_offer_made: {
        goodDate: true,
        nowhitespace: true
      },

      secPackage: {
        goodDate: true,
        nowhitespace: true
      },

      interimSecGranted: {
        goodDate: true,
        nowhitespace: true
      },


      interimSecDenied: {
        goodDate: true,
        nowhitespace: true
      },

      fullSecGranted: {
        goodDate: true,
        nowhitespace: true
      },

      medGranted: {
        goodDate: true,
        nowhitespace: true
      },      

      entranceOnDuty: {
        goodDate: true,
        nowhitespace: true
      }
    },

    messages: {
        interview:{
            required: ""
        },

        inp_slct_memo_recv:{
            required: ""
        },

        inp_job_offer_made:{
            required: ""
        },      


        secPackage:{
            required: ""
        },      


        interimSecGranted:{
            required: ""
        },      


        interimSecDenied:{
            required: ""
        },      


        fullSecGranted:{
            required: ""
        },      


        medGranted:{
            required: ""
        },      

        entranceOnDuty:{
            required: ""
        },  

      contractNumber: {
        required: 'Please enter a contract number.'
    }
}
  });

});
```

Now, this works for the interview field but it doesn't catch any other of the fields when an improper date is entered. I thought I would be able to just duplicate the values for the other names of text fields but this doesn't seem to be working.

Here is the HTML form:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">

        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-sm-4'>
                <div class='form-group'>


                    <form class="form-horizontal" name="updateInprocess" id="updateInprocess" action="https://afghanistan.wmt.usaid.gov/PAK_WMT/index.cfm/candidate/candidateInprocessUpdate">
                        <input name="can_id" value="25" type="hidden">
                        <input name="The_can_id" value="25" type="hidden">

                        <label for="user_title">Interview</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="interview" name="interview" value="02/13/2003" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" size="30" type="text" maxlength="45" />

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='col-sm-4'>
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <label for="user_firstname">Selection Memo Received</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="inp_slct_memo_recv" name="inp_slct_memo_recv" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" size="30" type="text" maxlength="45" value="01/02/2004" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='col-sm-4'>
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <label for="user_lastname">Job Offer Made</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="inp_job_offer_made" name="inp_job_offer_made" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" size="30" type="text" maxlength="45" value="" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



    <div class="col-xs-12">

        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-sm-4'>
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <label for="user_title">SEC Package Submitted</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="secPackage" name="secPackage" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" size="30" type="text" maxlength="45" value="" />

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='col-sm-4'>
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <label for="user_firstname">Interim Security Granted</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="interimSecGranted" name="interimSecGranted" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" size="30" type="text" maxlength="45" value="01/02/2007" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='col-sm-4'>
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <label for="user_lastname">Interim Security Denied</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="interimSecDenied" name="interimSecDenied" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" size="30" type="text" maxlength="45" value="" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-xs-12">

        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-sm-4'>
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <label for="user_title">Full Security Granted</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="fullSecGranted" name="fullSecGranted" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" size="30" type="text" maxlength="45" value="" />

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='col-sm-4'>
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <label for="user_firstname">Med Granted</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="medGranted" name="medGranted" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" size="30" type="text" maxlength="45" value="" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='col-sm-4'>
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <label for="user_lastname">Entrance on Duty</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="entranceOnDuty" name="entranceOnDuty" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" size="30" type="text" maxlength="45" value="" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-xs-12">

        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-sm-12'>
                <div class='form-group'>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-xs-12">

        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-sm-12'>
                <div class='form-group'>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


</div>



<div class="pull-left">
    <input type="submit" id="SaveCandidate" class="btn btn-success" value="Save Candidate">
</div>
</form>
<div class="pull-right">
    <div class="pull-right">
        <a class="btn btn-danger" href="#delete" role="button" data-toggle="modal">Delete Candidate</a>
        <a class="btn btn-warning" href="#drop" role="button" data-toggle="modal">Drop Candidate</a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I have double checked to make sure I am calling the proper named of the input fields but it does't seem to be working.

jsFiddle example setup: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mwoods98/cprswpfk/1/)

Comment: Do not use the [tag:jquery-validation-engine] tag for the jQuery Validate plugin... it's not the same thing.  Edited.  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry bout that. It was a suggestion. Noted.

Comment: Can you condense that jsFiddle down a bit?  There are a lot of unnecessary fields and styling just for showing the problem.

Comment: Why is your `<form>` element only around the first input?

Comment: If you want to write a custom method for a non-required field, then you also need to include `this.optional(element)`.  Look at your `strongPassword` method for usage of this.

Comment: As @Stryner said, something is wrong with your HTML.  Even in the jsFiddle, you seem to have the `form` container improperly nested inside of `div` elements.  Run the HTML through a validator and fix this.

Comment: The jsFiddle would also be easier for us to test if you didn't have all those `value` attributes pre-filled with content.

Comment: Ok working on the suggestions. I'll be back with answers and updates. Thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML was botched with the `form` tags improperly nested inside & straddling your `div` elements.

Moving the `form` tag outside of all of the `div` elements fixed the issue.

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/cprswpfk/5/**

---

You've written your custom `goodDate` function so that these fields cannot be left blank, effectively building `required` into it.

If these fields are *not* required, then you have to adjust your custom method using the `this.optional(element)`...

```
$.validator.addMethod("goodDate", function (value, element) {
    // put your own logic here, this is just a (crappy) example
    return this.optional(element) || value.match(/(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)[0-9]{2}/);
}, "Please enter a date in the format mm/dd/yyyy.");
```

**DEMO 2:  http://jsfiddle.net/cprswpfk/6/**

Comment: Thanks Sparky. Sorry about the whack HTML.  I appreciate your help on a Friday Afternoon.

Answer (score 0):

***Skip to bottom for pen***
Actually, I would use JavaScript to accomplish this.
The '/' should be at location 2 and 5 and your last character should be located at 9, as such:
01/34/6789 (where each number represents the character's location within the string).

```
var str = "12/22/1989";
var dSeperator = str.charAt(2);
var mSeperator = str.charAt(5);
var checkLength = str.length;

if(dSeperator === '/' &&
mSeperator === '/' &&
checkLength === 10)
{alert('this date is formatted as mm/dd/yyyy');}

else{alert('This date is NOT formatted as mm/dd/yyyy');}

for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    if(i === 0){
var month = str.substring(0, 2);
var dayEntered = str.substring(3, 5);
var yearEntered = str.substring(6, 10);

if(month > 12){alert('invalid month parameter entered');}
        //use swith case to get the set a days variable
switch(month){//get last day of month
    case '04':
            var days = 30
        alert(days)
    break;

    case '6':
            var days = 30
        alert(days)
    break;

    case '9':
            var days = 30
        alert(days)
    break;

    case '11':
            var days = 30
        alert(days)
    break;


    case '02':
            var days = 29
        alert(days)
    break;

    default:
            var days = 31
        alert(days)
    break;
}
}
    if(i === 1){//test days
if(days >= dayEntered){
alert('days entered correctly');}
else{alert(days + " !<= " + dayEntered);}
    }
if(i === 2){//check year, give your own min and max parameter
    //and if it is not leap year and month === '02' recheck day 
    //to make sure it is less or equal to 28 days
    alert('on step 2');
if(yearEntered >= 1989 && yearEntered <= 2020){//your own check
alert('year entered is between 1989 and 2020');}    
        if (yearEntered/400){
      result = true
    }
    else if(yearEntered/100){
      result = false
    }
    else if(yearEntered/4){
      result = true
    }
    else{
      result = false
    }
if(result === true && dayEntered <= 29){//end of validation
    alert('congratulations! you entered a valid date of '+dayEntered + "/" + month + "/" + yearEntered);
}
}
}

else{alert('This date is not formatted as mm/dd/yyy');}
```

Additionally, you should also check the value of each field to ensure that they are with in the correct range.  You should use a switch case for this as you will have months that have a varying number of days in the month.

The code snippet above will check each value and return an alert either telling the user the date is correct or incorrect.  Since you are not wanting to display anything for correct you can just remove those, and replace the other ones with a value of 'return false'. The finished result would look like

JavaScript

```
function checkdate(date, id){

    var error = document.getElementsByClassName('error')[id];
    var str = date;
    var dSeperator = str.charAt(2);
    var mSeperator = str.charAt(5);
    var checkLength = str.length;

    if(dSeperator != '/' ||
    mSeperator != '/' ||
    checkLength != 10)
    {return error.innerHTML = "incorrect date format!"}

    for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        if(i === 0){
    var month = str.substring(0, 2);
    var dayEntered = str.substring(3, 5);
    var yearEntered = str.substring(6, 10);

    if(month > 12 || month < 01){return error.innerHTML = "incorrect month";}
            //use swith case to get the set a days variable
    switch(month){//get last day of month
        case '04':
                var days = 30
        break;

        case '6':
                var days = 30
        break;

        case '9':
                var days = 30
        break;

        case '11':
                var days = 30
        break;


        case '02':
                var days = 29
        break;

        default:
                var days = 31
        break;
    }
    }
        if(i === 1){//test days
    if(days < dayEntered || dayEntered <= 0){
    return error.innerHTML = "incorrect day"}

        }
    if(i === 2){//check year, give your own min and max parameter
        //and if it is not leap year and month === '02' recheck day 
        //to make sure it is less or equal to 28 days
    if(yearEntered < 1988 || yearEntered > 2020){//your own check
    return error.innerHTML = "year is out of the allowed range";}    
            if ((yearEntered % 400) === 0){
          result = true
        }
        else if((yearEntered % 100) === 0){
          result = false
        }
        else if((yearEntered % 4) === 0){
          result = true
        }
        else{
          result = false
        }
    if(result === true && month === '02' && dayEntered > 28){//end of validation
        return error.innerHTML = "leap year only has 28 days!";}
        error.innerHTML = "";
    }
    }
    }
```

HTML

```
<script src="java.js" ></script>
<input id=0 type=text onblur="checkdate(this.value, this.id)" />
<p class=error></p>
<input id=1 type=text onblur="checkdate(this.value, this.id)" />
<p class=error></p>
<input id=2 type=text onblur="checkdate(this.value, this.id)" />
<p class=error></p>
<input id=3 type=text onblur="checkdate(this.value, this.id)" />
<p class=error></p>
```

Heres a Pen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zvZzQO